# Recover data from unbootable phone

Tags: data-recovery

I have a BQ Aquaris X Pro. During a phone call it suddenly started to reboot mid-call but it hung during the boot process (on the "second screen" where it says "Aquaris" in white, animated letters). Restarting the phone doesn't help, it still keeps hanging on the same spot (sometimes already on the first screen with the BQ logo).

So far a managed to enter recovery mode. I tried `View recovery logs`, but I didn't find any error messages. I tried to wipe the cache partition, but that didn't fix the problem.

So I want to recover a few files manually. In the recovery mode menu I tried to select `Mount \system` and then `Apply update from ADP`. The device shows up in the Windows 11 device manager:

[image]

I'm able to connect to the phone via ADB (after installing Android SDK and JDK):

```
C:\platform-tools_r33.0.2-windows\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
BL000110        sideload
```

I tried to access with `adb shell` but it returns with `error: closed`. I assume this is because of the "sideload mode" or could there be another reason?

I searched through quite a few articles and found possible causes like wrong USB drivers or not enabled USB-Debugging. I also noticed that in "Fastbootmode" (when I select `Reboot to bootloader` in the recovery menu), the device is not recognized in Windows:

[image]

At the moment I'm a little bit lost, any helpful hints are appreciated.

Comment: on locked bootloader your only chance to get (encrypted) dump off device is via [EDL](https://github.com/bkerler/edl) mode (deep flash cable or test point and prog_emmc_firehose_8953_ddr.mbn required, user [spark1991z](https://4pda.to/forum/index.php?showtopic=803644&view=findpost&p=77249488) may tell you)

Comment: @alecxs thanks, that seem to be quite a lot of work. If the is the only way, will there be way to decrypt the data?

Comment: No. but raw backup is recommended before trying to hack into. some modification might possible, if you're lucky you can root and enable adb by patching boot.img on locked bootloader. maybe prog_emmc_firehose_8953_ddr.mbn is generic so may work with preinstalled loaders from github, try without loader given first

Comment: @alecxs so if I understand correctly, your suggestion is just to do a backup in case s.th. goes wrong during the recovery process? (sorry, if the question seems superficial, I haven't worked with Android systems in such depth before, and still have a lot to catch up on)

Comment: Yes. you need EDL to patch boot anyway